# ASP.NET submit button event not executing

Tags: c#, asp.net, form-submit, code-behind

The code behind event for a form submit button is not executing.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" EnableEventValidation="true" Inherits="_Default" %>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
<input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="Update" runat="server" onclick="btnclick_Click" />
<asp:TextBox ID="tbStatus" enableViewState="true" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" 
    Width="296px" Height="67px" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
 </form>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
          tbStatus.Text = "Status: Page loaded";
    }
}

protected void btnclick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   tbStatus.Text += "\nButton clicked. ";
}
```

The btnclick_Click is never executing. If I instead change Page_Load to this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
          tbStatus.Text = "Status: Page loaded";
    }
} else {
      tbStatus.Text += "\nUpdated. (Page_Load PostBack). ";
}
```

Then the textarea is updated twice, on the third sudmit I ran into the error message:

```
The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.
```

I just want the button submit event to execute. Thanks in advance for any information on what I am doing wrong!

Comment: Why aren't u using server control?

Comment: Oh! I can't believe I have missed that! That was actually in my code too, terrible mistake! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the  to asp.net button

```
<asp:Button ID="Submit1" runat="server" Text="Update" OnClick="btnClick_Click"/>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void btnclick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   tbStatus.Text += Environment.NewLine + "Button clicked. ";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use server control itself to call page method.If you still want to continue with html `input` try

```
<input id="Submit1 "runat="server" type="button" onserverclick="btnclick_Click" />
```

For More on [HtmlButton.OnServerClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlbutton.onserverclick%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)